# Operators I didnot understand

Tags: c++

Following is the code that came into my exam. I commented those points which I didnot understood. Kindly let me know what is meant by following operators.

```
int main()
{
float ans=4;
ans*=10;
cout<<ans++<<endl;
ans-=22;
cout<<++ans<<endl;
ans/=4;
cout<<ans<<endl;
ans=int(ans)<<4; // WHAT is meant by <<4?
cout<<ans<<endl;
ans=int(ans)>>3; // WHAT is meant by >>4?
cout<<ans<<endl;
ans=int(ans)^0x000F; // WHAT is meant by ^0x000F?
cout<<hex<<ans<<endl;
ans=int(ans)&0x00F0; // WHAT is meant by &0x00F0?
cout<<hex<<ans<<endl;
cout<<hex<<(0x3567 & 0xF0f0)<<endl; // WHAT is meant by (0x3567 & 0xF0f0)?
cout<<hex<<(0x3567 | 0xF0f0)<<endl; // WHAT is meant by (0x3567 | 0xF0f0)?

cout<<hex<<~0x3567<<endl; // WHAT is meant by ~0x3567



getch();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I can't see how google couldn't help you with this.

Comment: We seriously need back the minimal understanding thing.

Comment: This is text book stuff. Why not read one?

Comment: @ScarletAmaranthv- Could we have a tag 'cannot be bothered' AKA 'little Britian'. SO we can tag such questions

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I googled but that didnot helped so I thought may you guys can help me. Looks like I was wrong :-(

Comment: @user3027531 - Learn about binary numbers - have they stopped teaching that at school

Comment: Why do people answer these? It's just an encouragement to even more such bad questions...

Comment: @EdHeal actually they didnot teach the topic but mistakenly gave the question in exam so out of curiosity I asked this question

Comment: @JBL I wish I could downvote you. This is very mean talk!!

Comment: @EdHeal Well, SO has its Grinch (who shall remain unnamed) so we can't have nice stuff :(.

Comment: @user3027531 There's nothing mean in this, don't take it personally either (but as you can see, your question has been deemed "Off topic", a while ago that could have been "Doesn't show a minimal understanding of the problem"). Have you read the site's rules? Especially [the first part](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). As it is very basic materials, any good reference would have showed you what these operators are (e.g. cppreference). StackOverflow isn't meant for this kind of questions, but actual programming problems you're struggling with.

Comment: @user3027531 - So some poor student walks into an exam about C programming. The first question is how to make a beef wellington (just out of curiosity). Seems rather harsh

Comment: @EdHeal I liked your sarcasm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<< >>
```

These are the *shift operators*. They shift the left operand by the number of bits given in the right operand. The direction of the shift depends on which of the two operators was used.

```
^
```

This is the *bitwise exclusive OR operator*. The result will have bits set where only one of the corresponding bits in both operands are set.

```
&
```

This is the *bitwise AND operator*. The result will have bits set where the corresponding bits in both operands are set.

```
|
```

This is the *bitwise inclusive OR operator*. The result will have bits set where at least one of the corresponding bits in both operands are set.

```
~
```

This is the *bitwise NOT operator*. It is the only unary operator of the ones you asked about (it has a single operand). The result is the one's complement of its operand (each bit is flipped).

Answer (score 0):

<< is shift left operator. and >> is shift right operator. & is bitwise and and | is bitwise or operator. ^ is bitwise xor operator.
For more details see here
[BitWise Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx)